# Error while creating new project with java 6

Tags: android, android-support-library, java-6

I am trying to create a new android project with java 6(JDK 1.6.0_18). 
My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.java6"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:20.0.0'
}
```

when I build it I see this error:

[image]

In my sdk manager:

[image][image]

I have got everyting installed but I still get this error. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version of the Android Design support library is the "22.2.0". You are using the "20.0.0", which doesn't exist. You can checkout the first version in the [developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html):

> You can then start using the Design library with a single new dependency: compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

It's important to note that you should be using the SDK compile version 22 to use it (check the major number version).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what should I do in my case? I need to use compileSkdVersion as 19 to use java 6

Comment: The major number of the support libraries should be the same as your compile version AFAIK, then you cannot use the design support library because it requires that you use the API 22 as your compile SDK version. That is because they use the new features of each API version (plus they have backoff functions for older Android versions).

Comment: Is this only for the design or for all the support libraries? I mean can't we use support libraries if the compileSdkVersion is 19?

Comment: The design support library appeared when the support libraries where in the 22 major version number. They put 22 to the first version of the design library because they wanted to have the same version numbers for all their support libraries I think. You can check the support library revision history here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html